# How to hide/disable preprompt messages?

Tags: configuration, startup, prompt

When we boot a GNU/linux system it shows lots of messages on stdout. And then, immediately before the prompt it shows something like this:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

I would like to hide that message. Which file do I need to edit to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two paragraphs are stored in [`/etc/motd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/motd.5.html); you just rename or delete it to get rid of them:

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo mv motd motd.old
```

The first line is specified in `/etc/update-motd.d/10-uname`; you can also delete it, or move it to another directory (making it hidden doesn't work).

Comment: Works great, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It's Motd (Message of the Day) service. In Ubuntu you can just disable it

```
systemctl stop motd-news.timer
systemctl disable motd-news.timer
```

I do not have a lot of experience with Debian, but I bet it's the same or very similar.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't valid for Raspi, as there's no `motd-news.timer` service. Also you'd need `sudo` to perform these commands. From what I can tell without deeper investigation, there's an init script `/etc/init/mounted-run.conf` which runs the `/etc/update-motd.d` scripts, but I wouldn't recommend to deactivate it before checking what else it's needed for.